# chrome plugin for recording and inputting data

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there some tool for Chrome with which I would be able to record action like: "click on field_n and enter some text" n times, and then play it by clicking some button?

I'm testing a web application and each time I reset a server I need to type username and two passwords, would be nice to do it by one click ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension called [iMacros for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en) to record macros for clicks and user input. It is very useful for simple test automation. An alternative for FireFox only is [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/).